# expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 , how to feed sparse matrix to LSTM layer in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using Keras to build one LSTM model. I have used TfidVectorizer(), to convert my data frame into words token. The transform method of tfidvectorizer() returns the csr_matrix which when I fed into LSTM layer , I always get an error

"ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2"

below is my python code

```
dfTest = pd.read_csv("C:\\ML\\test.csv",
                dtype={'url': np.str, 'name': np.str, 'verdict': np.int32},
                error_bad_lines = False,  sep=',', delimiter=',', header=0,
                names=['url', 'name', 'verdict'])

dataFrame = dfTest['url'] + " "+ dfTest['name']
target = dfTest['verdict']
lstData = []
for row in dataFrame:
  row = row.replace('http://www.', ' ')
  row = row.replace('.', ' ')
  row = row.replace('/', ' ')
  row = row.replace('com', ' ')
  lstData.append(row)

print(lstData)


tk1 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features  = 1000);

tk1.fit(lstData)
matrix  = tk1.transform(lstData)

print(matrix.shape)
print(matrix)


#data = np.reshape(data, data.shape + (1,))
target = np.reshape(target, target.shape + (1,))
print(target.shape)
print(target)

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(128, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2, input_shape= (5,)))
model1.add(Dense(1))
model1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model1.fit(matrix, y=target, batch_size=200, nb_epoch=5, verbose=1, 
validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

I am new to ML world, pl help to find out what I am doing wrong here.
May thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have transformed sparse matrix into array for and changed the dimensions of it ,and then it worked perfectly.

Here is the complete code.

```
  dfTest = pd.read_csv("C:\\ML\\test.csv",
              dtype={'url': np.str, 'name': np.str, 'verdict': np.int32},
              error_bad_lines = False,  sep=',', delimiter=',', header=0,
              names=['url', 'name', 'verdict'])

dataFrame = dfTest['url'] + " "+ dfTest['name']
target = dfTest['verdict']

tk1 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features  = 1000);

tk1.fit(dataFrame)
matrix  = tk1.transform(dataFrame)

matrix = matrix.toarray()
data = np.reshape(matrix, matrix.shape + (1,))
target = np.reshape(target, target.shape + (1,))
print(target)
print(data.shape)

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(128, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2, input_shape= 
data.shape[1:]))
model1.add(Dense(1))
model1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model1.fit(data, y=target, batch_size=200, nb_epoch=5, verbose=1, 
validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```